# How to call a function that takes a user inputted list, and then assigning that list to a global variable?

Tags: python, list, function, global

Lets say I have a function that takes a input of a strings and creates a list (here's mine):

```
def listString():
stringInput = input('Please input a single line of strings\n')
if len(stringInput) < 20:
    print("Error. Your input needs to have at least 20 characters")
    print(inputStringList())
elif len(stringInput) >= 20:
    delimiter = ' '
    var2 = stringInput.split(delimiter)
    print(var2)
```

How would I go about creating a global variable that stores that list so it can be passed into other functions? Obviously I need to call the function (possibly with a parameter) and assign it to a variable outside the function, but something so simple has made me confused.

Comment: what's `inputStringList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So globals are a Bad Thing and you should avoid them whenever possible, but you could do this:

```py
global_list = []


def list_string():  # leave camelCase for javascript -- we use snake_case in Python land.
    while True:
        string_input = input("Please input a single line of strings\n")
        if len(string_input) >= 20:
            break
        else:
            print("Error. Your input needs to have at least 20 characters")

    # string_input is now guaranteed to be a string of 20 characters or longer
    global global_list  # indicate that you're changing the global now
    global_list = string_input.split(' ')
```

That said, this is a bad idea and you should probably not do this at all. Debugging code that manages global state is hellish. Encapsulate this logic into an object and operate on it there.